# Using IlMerge in .Net 4

Tags: .net, dll, merge, ilmerge

For now I still cannot figure out how to use ILMerge.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

When I download and install it it says I need .Net Framework.

There are other stackoverflow posts to say install using NUGET.

Even after I have installed it using NUGET I am unsure as to how to proceed?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the helper NuGet package named "MSBuild ILMerge task". It will also install the ILMerge package if it's not yet there.

By default, it will merge all copy-local References into your main assembly.